# laravel 5 set Database with parameters from Session

Tags: php, database, session, laravel-5

I'm building an app where different users are accessing different databases.

In laravel 4, it was as easy as defining the database connection like so:

```
    'usertable' => [
        'driver'    => 'mysql',
        'host'      => env('DB_HOST'),
        'database'  => Session::get('table'), << works for laravel 4
        'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME'),
        'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'charset'   => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix'    => '',
        'strict'    => false,
    ],
```

However, laravel 5 throws an error:

> Class 'Session' not found in ...

I have tried to import Session in multiple ways and with every namespace I have found which could be Session's namespace, but nothing works at all and the error persists.

It seems like laravel5 would load the database class with all the possible connections before the Session class is autoloaded.

Is there another way to create database connections for different users? Or can someone suggest another way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Laravel provides a facade to access configuration at runtime.

```
Config::set('database.default', 'sqlite');
```

From the Laravel docs:

"Configuration values that are set at run-time are only set for the current request, and will not be carried over to subsequent requests."

I think this is a more viable solution. You can call this function and set the database from session for each request.

Or better, use a middleware and just mount it to handle the database setting before each request.

Comment: Doesn't work, Config is not accesible in the database file, too

Comment: You will need to do this in your controller. If I understand correctly, you need to connect each user to a different database based on their credentials ?

Comment: Yes, this is what I want to do, I need to specify the database within a connection only

Comment: I can only think of one way right now and have explained it in my answer. If you need dynamic database access at runtime then you will need to access the Config facade I think.

Comment: Here is a helpful link http://www.colorfultyping.com/multi-tenancy-in-laravel-switching-databases-at-runtime/

Comment: Actually it works as you said, though I don't really think this can be the only solution. I might set something nicer up here. Thank you!